# Shift+Enter does not work on Mac computer?

Tags: mac-os-x, cdfplayer

[image]

**When I click in the green box and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens. I am using a macbook with OS X El Captain. Is there other keys I can press?**

Comment: Which type of CDF is it (free or Enterprise) and which CDF Player are you using (free or Player Pro)?  Enterprise CDFs can evaluate input cells (using either free or Player Pro) and Player Pro can evaluate input cells of any type of CDF. See the Interactivity section [here](https://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html).

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot is showing the [CDF player](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) running as a browser plugin.  It's not Mathematica.

The CDF player does not allow you to run Mathematica code.  It can only *view* notebooks and run specially prepared CDF files.  Evaluating arbitrary code is not possible.  You need the full version of Mathematica for that.

Comment: Wow, okay feel a little less intelligent now. First time using the program, and stupid mistake. I got it open now in the actual program, thanks for your help!